# typeof creates new variable with underfined value if it doesn't exist or not

Tags: javascript, scope

I have this code

```
if(typeof foo == "undefined"){
    foo = "bar";
}
```

in global scope.
I know that when we get a reference to a variable then the interpreter checks if its already declared and if it doesn't it creates a new one.
Now in this sample code, will the expression

```
typeof foo == "undefined"
```

will create the *foo* with ***undefined*** value
or

```
    foo = "bar";
```

will create the variable *foo*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run the above code in console,

fact it does create global `foo = "bar";` if it is run for the first time, from the next time since foo is already created it does not satisfies the condition.

Chrome console output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDE6k.jpg

```
>if(typeof foo == "undefined"){
    foo = "bar";
}
>"bar"
```

Comment: It seems typeof foo wont create the variable.

Comment: @DragneelFPS: can you please just check if a global foo is actually defined. If thats the case it wont run. ie 2nd time and so on. I have tested this on console.

Comment: Yes, a global foo is created for the first time. Successive iterations will fail the loop. But my actual question was that does `typeof foo` creates the variable or not

Comment: @DragneelFPS: typeof does not create new variable, but  foo = "bar" will if foo is undefined.